# Displaying only weekdays

Tags: asp.net

I'm creating a website in Asp.net.

I need to display dates in labels(any control) in the below format.(only weekdays).

for example:

On 8/9/2016 'day display like **"8/9/2016 to 8/15/2016 "** ,
On 8/10/2016 'day display like **8/9/2016 to 8/15/2016**
On 8/11/2016 'day display like **8/9/2016 to 8/15/2016**
On 8/12/2016 'day display like **8/9/2016 to 8/15/2016**
On 8/13/2016 'day display like **8/9/2016 to 8/15/2016**
On 8/14/2016 'day display like **8/9/2016 to 8/15/2016**
On 8/15/2016 'day display like **8/9/2016 to 8/15/2016**

later on

On 8/16/2016 'day display like **8/16/2016 to 8/22/2016**
On 8/17/2016 'day display like **8/16/2016 to 8/22/2016**
On 8/18/2016 'day display like **8/16/2016 to 8/22/2016**
On 8/19/2016 'day display like **8/16/2016 to 8/22/2016**
On 8/20/2016 'day display like **8/16/2016 to 8/22/2016**
On 8/21/2016 'day display like **8/16/2016 to 8/22/2016**
On 8/22/2016 'day display like **8/16/2016 to 8/22/2016**

Could anyone please help with any logic.
Let me know if your not clear.

Comment: not clear, try to explain your scenario in brief

Comment: display #present day to #present day+ 7 days.                     
ex : 8/9/2016 to 8/22/2016                   

these dates should be fixed until 7 days..and later should be changed to 
8/16/2016 to 8/22/2016

Comment: Have you tried anything?, then post your code!

Comment: **label1.Text = Date.Today**

**label2.Text = Date.Today.AddDays(7)**

It will be displayed like 8/9/2016 and 8/15/2016

same this dates should be continued upto 7 days. and later should be changed to 

on **8/17/2016** ' th day should display like **8/17/2016 to 8/23/2016**

Answer (score 0):

To get the current date you can use `DateTime.Now` and to get the current date + 7 days you can use `DateTime.Now.AddDays(7)`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime todayPlusSeven = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7);
    lblDate.Text = String.Format("{0:MM-dd-yyyy} to {1:MM-dd-yyyy}", today, todayPlusSeven);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

declare @Date datetime 
set @Date='08/13/2016'
 
SELECT CASE DATEPART(weekday,@Date) 
WHEN 1 THEN 
convert(varchar(11),DATEADD(day,-2,@Date),101)
+' to '+
convert(varchar(11), DATEADD(day,4,@Date),101)
 WHEN 2 THEN 
convert(varchar(11),DATEADD(day,-3,@Date),101)
+' to '+ 
convert(varchar(11),DATEADD(day,3,@Date),101) 
 WHEN 3 THEN 
convert(varchar(11),DATEADD(day,-4,@Date),101)
+' to '+ 
convert(varchar(11),DATEADD(day,2,@Date),101) 
 WHEN 4 THEN 
convert(varchar(11),DATEADD(day,-5,@Date),101)
+' to '+ 
convert(varchar(11),DATEADD(day,1,@Date),101) 
 WHEN 5 THEN 
convert(varchar(11),DATEADD(day,-6,@Date),101)
+' to '+
convert(varchar(11), DATEADD(day,0,@Date),101) 
 WHEN 6 THEN 
convert(varchar(11),DATEADD(day,0,@Date),101)
+' to '+ 
convert(varchar(11),DATEADD(day,6,@Date),101)
  WHEN 7 THEN 
convert(varchar(11),DATEADD(day,-1,@Date),101)
+' to '+
 convert(varchar(11),DATEADD(day,5,@Date),101) 
  end as Daterange

Comment: run directly from sql server .no need any code to your asp.net C#.only run and get result into string.If u want result on selection of date.then make a proc and send your date in parameter. you will get required result

Comment: Thank you.. but it was showing from **sunday to saturday** , 
i want from **friday to thursday**.

Can you help with that.?

Comment: Can you format the code properly? It will help readers who find your answer later.

Comment: now you can set your date is @Date field .u will get date from friday to thursday

Comment: Hello Amit, thank you.
I'm getting result in SQL, can you help how to pull the result into Asp.net.